# How to Solve this Web view Error "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" in Android?

Tags: android, webview, ssl-certificate

When i **load** this url [www.droponway.com](https://www.droponway.com) into web view in android it show me this Error 
[image]

and **when i load** other url just like **www.facebook.com** it works fine.

**The Web View Code is below**

```
webViewHome.loadUrl(webURL);

    webViewHome.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            // do your stuff here
            pbProgressAction.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

private class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
    }
}
```

**i also add** method of ignoring SSL but nothing happend

```
private static void disableSSLCertificateChecking() {
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] { new X509TrustManager() {
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {
            // Not implemented
        }
    } };

    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it working in the web browser?, Because currently, I checked it's not working in web browser also.

Comment: The site is down

Comment: Sir but it is working in Microsoft edge browser

Comment: @ManoharReddy this site is working becasue when i run on proxy server in chrome it working file https://digimind.mobi/?__cpo=aHR0cHM6Ly9kcm9wb253YXkuY29t

Comment: It is down , Please check in a private window . May be you are getting cached site .

Comment: @ManoharReddy i know this site is not working on chrome but working on other browser and proxy server.Is that issue of SSL?

Comment: Its not working in firefox either , Its only working on edge . I am not sure whats the issue

Answer (score 1):

It seems your http**s** URL is not private. If you want to check that connection is private, open browser in incognito mode or (other browser) and load the URL.

If you get privacy warning such as : "Your connection is not private"
add the following client to webview.

```
private class MyWebViewClient(private val binding: FragmentSearchBinding) : WebViewClient() {
    override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String?): Boolean {
        view?.loadUrl(url!!)
        return false
    }

    override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String?) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url)
        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    }

    override fun onReceivedError(
        view: WebView?,
        request: WebResourceRequest?,
        error: WebResourceError?
    ) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error)
    }
    //Important part
    override fun onReceivedSslError(
        view: WebView?,
        handler: SslErrorHandler?,
        error: SslError?
    ) {
        handler?.proceed()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Seerat Abbas Khan, Did this solution help you ? Please provide your results. It will help others too.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your url in browser , i think site is down check the same